# How to access methods from an object of type object

Tags: c#, class, object

I have two classes named Road and City, they have the following methods:

"class Road"

```
public Road()
    {
      public int getId()
      {
          return this.id;
      }
    }
```

"class City"

```
public City()
    {
      public string getName()
      {
          return this.name;
      }
    }
```

In another class named Image, I create instances of City and Road of the type Object

Example

```
    Object o = new Object();
    City c = cc.getCityByCoordinates(coordinates);
    o = c;
```

Now how can I access the methods from City.class on the "o" object? Like o.getName();  -
If that is even possible, please help.

Comment: What is `cc`? And no it's not possible to call a method defined in `City` on an `object`. You'd have to cast the `object` to `City`.

Comment: Why would you save your data into an `Object`? You lose its strong-type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily do this by casting to "City":

```
City c = o as City;
c.getName();
```

Note that the `as` operator will return null if the cast is invalid, so you should check before using it:

```
City c = o as City;
if (c != null)
    c.getName();
```

The other way is to use the `is` operator and a C-style cast:

```
if (o is City)
   ((City)o).getName();
```

A word of warning, downcasting like this is a "code smell". Look at your code and see *why* you need to do this. Perhaps it should be stored in an interface instead. `Object` variables can also be a "code smell", and used only if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I access the methods from `City` class on the "o" object?

Cast it:

```
Object o = new Object();
City c = cc.getCityByCoordinates(coordinates);
o = c;
string name = ((City)o).getName();
```

If `o` is not *really* a `City` then you'll get an exception at run-time.  To check if `o` is a `City` before trying to cast it, you can use `as`:

```
City c2 = o as City;  // c2 will be `null` if o is not castable to City
if(c2 != null)
   string name = c2.getName();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
City cityFromObject = o as City;
if(null != cityFromObject) {
   // do something with cityFromObject.getName();
}
```

Comment: Don't write `null != something` in C#.

Comment: @manojlds, why not? It might be backwards from `something != null`, but it does give you protection from `something = null`.

Comment: @gunr2171 - It's ugly :) It was started as a practice to avoid doing assignments when you wanted to do equality check in languages like C. It is not possible in C#.

Comment: @gunr2171 - Exactly, you can't do `if(something = null)` in C#.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use reflection to retrieve the result off of City.

```
        MethodInfo mi = c.GetType().GetMethod("getName");
        var result = mi.Invoke(o, null).ToString()
```

Comment: Technically yes... but you would only do this if you didn't know the type ahead of time (and so could not cast). If possible, casting is much faster than reflection.